# Quick confirmation on check for substring in Python 3.6

Tags: python

I write my code in Python 3.8.9 with this line, which works:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    if "AlreadyExistsException" in e:
```

When deploying it in a Python 3.6 environment, I get this error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'AlreadyExistsException' is not iterable
```

Could someone help confirming that the operation to check for the existence of a substring `AlreadyExistsException`  in the error string `e` like above does not work in Python 3.6? I don't have Python 3.6 to test this out and too hesitated to install it to test this error. And if this is true, what is a workable way to check for substring in Python 3.6?

Comment: I was curious, so I checked - but in Python 3.8.9, the same exception is thrown. Which isn't surprising, since exceptions are in fact not iterable. You say, that "my code in Python 3.8.9 [..], which works" - you'll need to provide a more complete code example and show where this `AlreadyExistsException` is coming from, because it certainly doesn't happen for any exception. A possible cause is that you're using some custom exception from a package that had an implementation for Python 3.8+ that allowed accessing the exception as an iterable, while older versions didn't, specific to the package

Comment: Additionally, `'some string' in 'some other string'` has worked since Python 2, so there won't be a difference there between 3.x versions.

Comment: The value for ```e``` is a string, in my case it is ```An error occurred (AlreadyExistsException) when calling the CreateStack operation: Stack [xxxxx] already exists```. All that statement does above is to check if a substring ```AlreadyExistsException``` exists in that longer string. And that throws the error. It does not happen in Python 3.8.9.

Comment: It *does* in fact happen in 3.8.9, for any normal exception, like I just stated. But if you refuse to provide more information, you're preventing yourself from getting some help. Also note that `e` wouldn't be a string, although it can certainly be converted to one in many cases by passing it to `str()` and you could then use `in` to check for substrings, although that's a bad way to check for exception type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to check for a specific type of `Exception` would be:

```
try:
    ...
except AlreadyExistsException as e:
    # do something in response to this specific exception
    ...
except (SomeOtherException, AndAnotherException) as e:
    # do something in response to those specific exceptions
    ...
```

Comment: Ok. I think I understand your point. I do a ```print(type(e))``` and it turns out ```e``` is not a string, but an object ```<class 'botocore.errorfactory.AlreadyExistsException'>```

Comment: Yeah, that's it - and there may have been some special reason for a specific exception to allow you to skip the casting to a string. The above is the correct way to go either way, so I hope that solves your problems.